# Putting Money Onto Your Xbox One

Tags: xbox-one

Question: How do I put specific funds on my xbox account without using a credit card?

I own an Xbox One and right now I'm interested in buying a DLC, but problem is I lack the funds by about £0.05. I know there is no gift card/redeemable code but if there is somesort of code I can use it would be most convenient.
Is there anyway I can put exactly £0.05 on my account without using my credit card? I've had previous issues with my credit card online and I don't want to risk it again, and PayPal wouldn't be good either. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to increase your funds by a specific amount without a credit card. Your only option is to buy a prepaid card instead.

In fact, for such a small amount as 5 cents, I doubt MS would let you use your credit card either, since they might actually lose money from paying commissions to your credit card company. They'd most likely force you to charge a greater amount instead, such as 10 GBP.

As an alternative, there are so-called [**virtual credit cards**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_payment_number), which are said to be more secure than regular credit cards (but in return can only be used for online payment). Contact your credit card supplier for more information, including whether they offer such a service.

Comment: Shame really, I have to pay atleast £5 for something so insignificant. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The smallest amount you can do is a 1.00 gift card, which you can buy from the [Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/d/xbox-digital-gift-card/cfq7ttc0k63h/0002?icid=GiftCardsCat-Hero1-shopgiftcard-101717) (the link is for the U.S. store).  This option however still requires the use of a credit card.

The only other option you can do is go to an actual brick and mortar store and purchase a gift card there, but they likely won't have amounts smaller than 25.00.

If you have a certain amount already on your account, the credit card will be used to cover the remaining balance after subtracting whats on your account from the purchase total.  This is the only way I know of that will allow you to spend the minimum .05 you are looking to spend.  Again, this will require you use a credit card though.

Comment: I live in the UK, and the smallest gift card you can purchase is £5.

Comment: @Jake even on the online store? I find that strange that they don't give you further options.

Comment: I actually live in a British Overseas Territory, and the only place you can get Physical Gift Cards only have above £10.

Comment: @Jake I think in America the lowest is 15 dollars you can get in a store. Still doesn't help you out though :/